# Update a column that has duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

I am using SQL server 2008R2 and have a table called `AirNewformat` .This table is mostly searched by `ID` column which has many duplicates. I wanted to update same table by adding a column called processed where first value of `ID` is updated as `'N'` in processed column and rest of the duplicates updated as `'D'` in the processed column. Currently i have all the records updated either as `N` or `D` but i want see an update like below example. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
ID       Processed
---       ---------
12       N
12       D
12       D
13       N
13       D
13       D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code if you might ( **SQL Fiddle** for this: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03991/6** ):

Update first record in every `ID` group as `N`:

```
UPDATE 
  A
SET
  A.Processed = 'N'
FROM
  (
     SELECT ID, Processed, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS row_num FROM AirNewformat
  ) AS A
  INNER JOIN 
  (
     SELECT
         C.ID,
         MIN(C.row_num) AS min_row_num
     FROM
     (
       SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS row_num FROM AirNewformat
     ) AS C
     GROUP BY C.ID
  ) AS B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.row_num = B.min_row_num;
```

Update all the rest of records as `D`:

```
UPDATE 
  AirNewformat
SET
  AirNewformat.Processed = 'D'
WHERE
  ISNULL(AirNewformat.Processed, '') = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
;with cte as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by ID order by ID) N, processed from airNewformat
)

update cte
set processed = case when N = 1 then 'N'
    when N >1 then 'D' end;
```